# Background image obstructing Canvas plot in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Im a beginner in Tkinter and trying to create a GUI which has a background watermark (image file) visible across multiple pages. However, the plots through Canvas  should take a priority above the watermark and be visible when displayed over the window. Present code hides the canvas plot below the watermark image (Page One). How do I change this priority on image display?
Below is my code

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Nov  3 15:43:02 2016
@author: tkinter beginner
"""
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg, Figure
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne,PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)       
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=20,column=6,sticky=W)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

root = Test()
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file='back_img.gif')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=200, y=50, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[Click to see the error png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZDgM.png)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JonathanMee Code tested on Linux to re-produce the problem (windows hangs due to matplotlib problem). back_img.gif can be any gif file.

Comment: I got that. My statement is, this is you're whole program, not a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example. I'm requesting that you take time on the debugger to find which *part* of this program Windows is failing on, and post that rather than the program in it's entirety.

Comment: @JonathanMee the issue is not with program on windows failing but plotting using canvas over a background image (as seen on Linux). To re-produce the problem (check the attached image), this much piece of code is necessary. Also, may be there is a better way to declare background image, hence I put the current code length. The code failing on windows is another issue..

Comment: Is it possible that you could pare this code down to several Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples placing them in several questions?

Comment: @JonathanMee Edited the code to highlight the clash issue of canvas image with background image.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work on this. I believe this has been sharpened to the point that one of the Tkinter gurus can provide you some helpful feedback!